# How can I avoid a DOMAIN ERROR using matrix inversion ⌹ in Dyalog

Tags: matrix, apl, inversion, dyalog

I have been porting old APL*PLUS PC functions that run on DOS to Dyalog and have had great success.  But one function runs fine on APL*PLUS PC but gave me a DOMAIN ERROR on Dyalog.  I traced the problem to a matrix invertion using ⌹.

Here is an example of what I am seeing:

```
      F←6.91E9 5.655E9
      I←¯0.0144722 ¯0.01897385

      Z←I⌹2 2⍴F[1],(÷-F[1]),F[2],÷-F[2]
DOMAIN ERROR
      Z←I⌹2 2⍴F[1],(÷-F[1]),F[2],÷-F[2]
         ∧
```

This error was also observed on GNU_64 APL.

I created my own DIVIDE function to work with 2x2 arrays:

```
 Z←I2 DIVIDE M22;A;B;C;D
 A←M22[1;1] ⋄ B←M22[1;2] ⋄ C←M22[2;1] ⋄ D←M22[2;2]
 Z←÷(A×D)-B×C
 Z←Z×(2 2)⍴D,(-B),(-C),A
 Z←Z+.×I2
```

```
      Z←I DIVIDE 2 2⍴F[1],(÷-F[1]),F[2],÷-F[2]
      Z
4.625648461E¯13 122089494.5
```

Check answer:

```
    (2 2⍴F[1],(÷-F[1]),F[2],÷-F[2])+.×Z
¯0.0144722 ¯0.01897385
```

DIVIDE gives the correct answer

Comment: ⎕FR←1287 is the easiest fix in dyalog

Comment: Where can I find documentation?

Comment: I found the documentation and tried it.  It works.  Thank you for the help.